# If $M$ is compact subset of a metric space $X$, then it is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

I have proved this theorem using open cover definition. I also read that this result can be proved using sequence definition. That is, if a set $M$ is compact then every sequence in $M$ has a convergent subsequence.
Using this definition, book showed that $M$ is bounded.

$Proof:$
Let $M$ be unbounded set , then there is a sequence $(y_n)$ which is unbounded, $ie.$ $d(y_n,b)>n$ where $b$ is fixed element. Now this sequence cannot have a convergent subsequence since convergent sequence will be bounded.
I have a doubt in the last statement since unbounded sequence can have a convergent subsequence and bounded subsequence. Please tell me what this last line actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is not perfect, since an unbounded sequence can indeed have a convergent subsequence. However, it is correct that such a sequence as the one mentioned in that proof cannot have a convergent subsequence. That's because not only that sequence is unbounded as *every subsequence of that sequence is unbounded* too. In fact, if $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, then, for each $k\in\Bbb N$, $d(y_{n_k},b)>n_k$. So, since $\lim_{k\to\infty}n_k=\infty$, the sequence $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is indeed unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

if $(y_{n_k})$ is a convergent subsequence,  to some $y$, then $n_k<d(y_{n_k},b)\leq d(y_{n_k},y) + d(y,b)$, for every $n_k$ and $d(y_{n_k},y) + d(y,b)$ is bounded since $d(y_{n_k},y)$ converges to $0$; that's a contradiction.